# How can i make that the user can select if the camera will be behind the player or not?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the original code make the camera follow the player:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToFollow;       //Public variable to store a reference to the player game object
    private Vector3 offset;         //Private variable to store the offset distance between the player and camera

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //Calculate and store the offset value by getting the distance between the player's position and camera's position.
        offset = transform.position - objectToFollow.transform.position;
    }

    // LateUpdate is called after Update each frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Set the position of the camera's transform to be the same as the player's, but offset by the calculated offset distance.
        transform.position = objectToFollow.transform.position + offset;
        transform.LookAt(objectToFollow.transform);
    }
}
```

And this is what i tried to do but then the player it self(ThirdPersonController) is not rotating according to where he move.

With the original script above he does.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToFollow;       //Public variable to store a reference to the player game object
    public bool behindPlayer = false;

    private Vector3 cameraStartPos;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        cameraStartPos = transform.position;

        // Put the camera behind the player
        if (behindPlayer == true)
        {
            transform.position = (objectToFollow.transform.position - (objectToFollow.transform.forward * 5) + (objectToFollow.transform.up * 2));
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (behindPlayer == true)
        {
            transform.position = (objectToFollow.transform.position - (objectToFollow.transform.forward * 5) + (objectToFollow.transform.up * 2));
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = cameraStartPos;
        }
    }

    // LateUpdate is called after Update each frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = objectToFollow.transform.position;
        transform.LookAt(objectToFollow.transform);
    }
}
```

I want that the camera will be automatic behind the player already without the need to change the camera position in the scene if the user want by using the bool variable.

But the script now is not like in the above:

With this line in the LateUpdate:

```
transform.position = objectToFollow.transform.position;
```

Using the bool false/true it's not changing the camera position at all.
Without this line the player will move and the camera will follow but the player will not rotate and not move as above.

What i want is just like the first script but with the behindPlayer variable.

Answer (score 0):

A working script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform target;

    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 offsetPosition;

    [SerializeField]
    private Space offsetPositionSpace = Space.Self;

    [SerializeField]
    private bool lookAt = true;

    private void Update()
    {
        Refresh();
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        if (target == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Missing target ref !", this);

            return;
        }

        // compute position
        if (offsetPositionSpace == Space.Self)
        {
            transform.position = target.TransformPoint(offsetPosition);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = target.position + offsetPosition;
        }

        // compute rotation
        if (lookAt)
        {
            transform.LookAt(target);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.rotation = target.rotation;
        }
    }
}
```

In the inspector set the offset for example to 0,5,-12 and as target set for example ThirdPersonController. And attach the script to the Camera(Camera must be tagged as MainCamera if the target is ThirdPersonController since the ThirdPersonController ThirdPersonUserControl script is looking for the MainCamera).

And the camera doesn't have to be a child of the target the camera can be in any place in the Hierarchy.

Anyway it's working.